# Microsoft BIDS How to clear table data before new transfer?

Tags: sql, sql-server, bids

I have a database from which I am pulling rows from, manipulating the data a bit and then putting into another table. Every time I run the package, it doesnt remove any data from the destination and thus grows by X number of rows each time.

Is there any way that I can clear the destination before adding the new rows?

Comment: When you say 'pulling' rows, are you just running a query on the data? If so this won't actually remove the rows from the database, you would need to run a separate delete query to do this.

Comment: `DELETE FROM Table` ? `TRUNCATE Table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can run a truncate statement to clear all records from the table.

`TRUNCATE TABLE YourTableName`